# Process Rejections Elasticsearch

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes

we're operating an ELK cluster on a single host. The current setup includes:
3 node ( 1 master-nodata, 2 master-data) containers
2 logstash containers (for app and for container logs)
2 kibana containers(1 for administrative purposes only)

I noticed that we get process rejections on write threadpool only on node 3 container. If I understood it correctly this happens when cpu cant handle the queue. We are using 2x E5 2620 intel xeon processors on this host. Each node has 16GB heap, each logstash has 4gb heap and there is also plenty of ram left after logstash and elasticsearch heaps.

I have more shards than i normally should have so i suppose that might be causing a problem on these nodes in particular in this subject. We changed our indexing system but it will take about a month until it settles. I've  thought of a couple solutions but not sure how they will work so i'd like your knowledge on this.

1. If i add 2 more data node containers to this cluster and keep the total shard count for each index at 2 will it make some room as it begins to spread the shards evenly to all nodes?
2. Is it possible to increase the thread count for write threadpool? If yes where? I dont think increasing or decreasing queue size might effect this in a positive way. So I'd like to know if i can change thread count directly.
3. When the new index structure settles as i mentioned above, will it affect this situation in a positive way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All the stack components are competing for the resources on that single host. Adding more data containers on the same host might not really help. You need to spread the load on more hosts, that's how you can scale.

Comment: It doesnt seem possible to add more hosts, I suggested to scale horizontally but at least for the foreseeable future I need to get the most out of this single machine. The machine has 188gbs of ram 2x E5 2620 cpu's so it is kind of an overkill machine and i'm using around 60 gigs of the ram in total i'd like to think that there is a way to get some more performance out of this machine.

Comment: It would probably be helpful to see the detailed configuration of all your stack components. Also can you confirm that E5 2620 intel xeon processors have 6 cores?

Comment: sorry my mistake, cpus are 2640 not 2620. Here is the lscpu output for the processors:

Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    10
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          2
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39

Comment: You should update your question, as it's more legible. Also don't forget the detailed configurations of all your stack components